# insert dictionary int and string not working (swift4)

Tags: swift, dictionary, struct

I am trying to insert another dictionary entry into a struct this is not working. I am trying to use both a int and String for the dictionary.

```
 @IBAction func move(_ sender: Any) {

        Bad2.addx.insert(0:"dan", at: 0)


    }
    struct Bad2 {
        static var addx: [Int:String] = [1:"joe", 2:"fen"]

    }
```

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an `insert` function because there is no notion of ordering in a dictionary. The dictionary `[0: "A", 1: "B"]` is equivalent to `[1: "B", 0: "A"]`. You should reevaluate what you actually want this object to do, and if you really want a dictionary or something else.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you add a key/value to a dictionary. You need:

```
Bad2.addx[0] = "dan"
```

Comment: is there a way to add a number with dan like dan score 2?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? And how is it related to your question?

Comment: it appears that you code only adds a string to the dictonar. How could I add both a int and string

Comment: The code in my answer matches your code. You have defined `addx` to be a simply dictionary with `Int` keys and `String` values. So my answer shows you how to add another key/value pair to that dictionary. The key is `0` and the value is `"dan"`. That's all your dictionary can hold. If you want more data then you need something more than a simple dictionary with `Int` keys and `String` values.

Comment: Would would you recommend I do if I needed to store both a int and a string like. Like name and finish time. Something like runningTime = [String, int]

Comment: Create a struct with the properties you need. Then store instances of the struct in either an array or dictionary depending on your needs.